IBNR development factor calculation in data.table
Given the following table:
IBNR <- data.table(IncurredYear=c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2022,2022,2023),
                   DevYear=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,0,1,0),
                  Amount=c(100,80,70,50,70,40,35,50,45,80))

I would like to calculate to get the "Amount cumulative":
IBNRCumulative <- data.table(IncurredYear=c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2022,2022,2023),
                   DevYear=c(0,1,2,3,0,1,2,0,1,0),
                   Amount=c(100,80,70,50,70,40,35,50,45,80),
                   AmountCumulative=c(100,180,250,300,70,110,145,50,95,80))

and after reshaping from long to wide:
IBNRtriang <- dcast(IBNRCumulative, IncurredYear ~ DevYear, fun.aggregate = list(sum), value.var = c("AmountCumulative"))

I would like to derive the DevFactors:
DevelopmentFactor <- data.table(DevYear=c(0,1,2,3),
                                DevFactor = c(1.75, 1.362, 1.2, 1))

where: 1.75 = (180+110+95)/(100+70+50), 1.362 = (250+145)/(180+110) and so on, the last one should be 1.
Can you help me to find a compact and elegant way to get it done? Thanks.

I did it in this way:
# part 1
setorder(IBNR, IncurredYear, DevYear)
IBNRCumulative  <- IBNR[, AmountCumulative := cumsum(Amount), by = c('IncurredYear')]

# part 2
num_cols <- dim(IBNRCumulative)[2]
num_rows <- dim(IBNRCumulative)[1]
OnesVector <- rep(1, num_cols-1)
DevPeriods <- 0:(num_cols-2)
T2ChainLadderCountDevFactors <- data.table("DevPeriod" = DevPeriods, "DevFactor" = OnesVector)

for(i in 1:(num_cols-2))
{  
  RelevantTab_i <- T2ChainLadderCountTriang[1:(num_rows-i),(1+i):(2+i)]
  i_t1 <- RelevantTab_i[,1]
  i_t2 <- RelevantTab_i[,2]
  DevFactor_i <- prod(i_t2)/prod(i_t1)
  T2ChainLadderCountDevFactors[i,2] <- DevFactor_i
}

any suggestion to do it in a more elegant way?
